# How do I multiply based on values in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, join, merge

How do I multiply values in a larger dataframe based on values in another dataframe, according to the category, while working in R?

The smaller data frame is like so:

| travel | time |
| --- | --- |
| bike | 2.5 |
| car | 1.0 |
| walk | 5.0 |

The larger dataframe is like so:

| year | travel | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | bike | 25 |
| 2010 | car | 70 |
| 2010 | walk | 9.2 |
| 2011 | car | 71 |
| 2011 | walk | 8.2 |
| 2010 | bike | 23.1 |

Then I want a new column in the second dataframe as the product (rate * time = distance in this example), according on the 'travel' category based on each one's specific rate from the first dataframe.

Comment: Just do `library(data.table);setDT(df2)[df1, distance := rate * time, on = .(travel)]` or with `dplyr` `df2 %>% left_join(df1 %>% select(-year)) %>% mutate(distance = rate * time)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a merge/join operation. Two good references for those are [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272). (As such, this question is mostly a duplicate of the first one.)

### base R

```r
both <- merge(larger, smaller, by = "travel", all.x = TRUE)
transform(both, distance = rate*time )
#   travel year rate time distance
# 1   bike 2010 25.0  2.5     62.5
# 2   bike 2010 23.1  2.5     57.8
# 3    car 2010 70.0  1.0     70.0
# 4    car 2011 71.0  1.0     71.0
# 5   walk 2010  9.2  5.0     46.0
# 6   walk 2011  8.2  5.0     41.0
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(larger, smaller, by = "travel") %>%
  mutate(distance = rate*time)
#   year travel rate time distance
# 1 2010   bike 25.0  2.5     62.5
# 2 2010    car 70.0  1.0     70.0
# 3 2010   walk  9.2  5.0     46.0
# 4 2011    car 71.0  1.0     71.0
# 5 2011   walk  8.2  5.0     41.0
# 6 2010   bike 23.1  2.5     57.8
```

### data.table

(as akrun commented)

```r
library(data.table)
smallerDT <- as.data.table(smaller)
largerDT <- as.data.table(larger)
largerDT[smallerDT, distance := rate*time, on = .(travel)]
#     year travel  rate distance
#    <int> <char> <num>    <num>
# 1:  2010   bike  25.0     62.5
# 2:  2010    car  70.0     70.0
# 3:  2010   walk   9.2     46.0
# 4:  2011    car  71.0     71.0
# 5:  2011   walk   8.2     41.0
# 6:  2010   bike  23.1     57.8
```

---

Data

```r
smaller <- structure(list(travel = c("bike", "car", "walk"), time = c(2.5, 1, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
larger <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2010L), travel = c("bike", "car", "walk", "car", "walk", "bike"), rate = c(25, 70, 9.2, 71, 8.2, 23.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```